# In Graph Theory, what is the difference between a tour and a trail? Are they the same thing?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

To my understanding, a tour is a walk with no repeated edges. I have found it hard to find a good definition for a trail, but the two seem very similar.

If they're the same, why have two terms for one thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

All introductory graph theory textbooks that I've checked (Bollobas, Bondy and Murty, Diestel, West) define **path**, **cycle**, **walk**, and **trail** in almost the same way, and are consistent with [Wikipedia's glossary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms). One point of ambiguity: it depends on your author whether the reverse of a path is the same path, or a different one.

I occasionally worry about people talking about paths and cycles and not assuming that they're simple, but graph theory textbooks don't do this (fortunately!).

It is not universal to define **tour** to begin with, and it's not done in a consistent way. I think that the motivation to do this is often: "Well, it's conventional to talk about Euler tours of a graph. Can we first define general tours, and then say that an Euler tour is a tour with some special property?" This leads to

- defining tours to be walks that traverse each edge at least once (Bondy and Murty)
- defining tours to be closed trails (Wikipedia)
- defining tours in the same way as trails (the source you consulted)

The word **circuit** is also ambiguous, though it most commonly means a closed trail.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a book that defines walk, path (=walk with no repeated vertices), and trail (=walk with no repeated edges):
https://books.google.fr/books?id=vaXv_yhefG8C&pg=PA162&hl=de&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false

But it doesn't define tour. Incidentally, I feel like *tour* being used only for paths or trails where *all* vertices or edges are used.